# How can I use `send-keys` or some other Tmux command to run a key-binding programmatically?

Tags: debian, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I want to use `send-keys` or some other Tmux command to execute the following key-binding (`M-l`) using `prefix`: `C-a` and `send-prefix`: `C-a`

```
bind M-l send-keys -R \; clear-history \; send-keys C-l \; display "█▓░ clear"
```

I've tried `send-keys C-a M-l` and `send-keys C-a C-a M-l`, but none seems to work.

I guess the reason is that Tmux sends these keys to (the process running in) the active pane without "intercepting" them, i.e. it doesn't act on `prefix`: `C-a` being input using `send-keys`.

How can execute a key-binding in Tmux programatically using `send-keys` (or some other command) instead of pressing the keys on the keyboard manually?

Answer (score 5):

You can't trigger tmux key bindings with send-keys. You could just run the commands the key is bound to instead.